# What happens after actionPerformed executes?

Tags: java, swing

What happens after the execution of `actionPerformed`? Is there any way I can go back to the main class of the program after `actionPerformed` executes?

Here is the sample of the code:

```
public final class JavaGame extends JFrame {

    public JavaGame(){
        int x = cache();
        JButton butt = new JButton("NEW");

        newG gameX = new newG();
        butt.addActionListener(gameX);
    }

    public class gameFunction implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == butt){
                //do something logic here. Like go to another stage of the game
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Success!");
            }
        }
    }

    public cache(){
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaGame();
    }

}
```

After `actionPerformed` runs, what happens next?

In my real code, after `actionPerformed` runs, the stage of my game is still the same. How can I go back to `main` so that I can start a new stage without closing and opening the program again?

Comment: I hate to be immature but if(e.getSource() == butt) lol.

Comment: This is not how a GUI-application works. You just start it and keep handling events that are dispatched to your listeners. So when actionperformed terminates nothing more happens beside your application waiting for the next event.

Comment: I think you would benefit greatly from working through the [official Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), or at least the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) sections.

Comment: By the way, I think this is a decent question on its own, but I think you should delete the *"In my real code, after actionPerformed runs, the stage of my game is still the same. How can I go back to main so that I can start a new stage without closing and opening the program again?"* part and let the question stand alone. There isn't enough info here to diagnose a problem with your actual game, which could have a different cause, and the presence of that risks your question being closed. I suggest creating a new question about that if you're still having issues after reading the answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main you show the JFrame:

```
new JavaGame().setVisible(true);
```

and then you return from main.

In the background there is a thread running, called EDT, event dispatching thread.
On that thread button clicks, repainting and so on are handled.

That should be done in a short period, to keep the user interface responsive, not freezed.

So you need to work **event driven**: you can often add a listener for some specific event, like closing the JFrame, menu items, buttons. Those listeners are called with an event object specifying what happened. You called addActionListener.

The control flow is to keep the button click responsive, and doing hard work a bit later:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JavaGame.this.createANewAvatar();
        }
    });
}
```

And then somewhere have a

```
private void createNeewAvatar() { ... }
```

This hard to follow control-flow (because fragmentary) needs a good naming, and organized sources.

Comment: what does the `JavaGame.this` refer to? gameFunction?

Comment: There are many nested classes here: `JavaGame.this` is like `this` an implicit field of the object. It also has a `Runnable.this` for instance. With `JavaGame.this` you have access to the members (methods, fields) of the JavaGame object. In general you can leave it out and simple call `createANewAvatar()`.

Answer (score 2):

As a concrete example, this simple [game](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) includes a <kbd>Reset</kbd> button that invokes `reset()` on the game's model. The listening view see a `null` value of `arg` as a signal to update the display accordingly.

[image]